# How to make a histogram for non-numeric variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

**Sample data**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dummy = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 
        'brand': ['MS', 'Apple', 'MS', 'Google', 'Apple'], 
        'quarter': ['2017Q2', '2017Q2', '2017Q2', '2016Q1', '2015Q1']}

dummyData = pd.DataFrame(dummy, columns = ['id', 'brand', 'quarter'])
dummyData


# id    brand   quarter
# 0 1   MS      2017Q2
# 1 2   Apple   2017Q2
# 2 3   MS      2017Q2
# 3 4   Google  2016Q1
# 4 5   Apple   2015Q1
```

Now I want to plat a histogram using matplotlib and pandas, here the description

- X Axis : Quarter
- Y Axis : Count of values
- Histogram Bin: Filled with brand like 2017Q2 have two color values for MS and Apple
- Legends : Brand Name

I have a R background and its pretty easy using ggplot, I want to do the same in Python but I am not finding any suitable code, I am getting below mentioned error

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: What's the code that throws the error?

Comment: Please show the code leading to this error.

Comment: Show us what the ggplot output looks like in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` + `count` + `unstack` + `plot` -

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')

dummyData.groupby(['quarter', 'brand'])\
      .brand.count().unstack().plot.bar(legend=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For reference, this is what is plotted -

```
brand    Apple  Google   MS
quarter                    
2015Q1     1.0     NaN  NaN
2016Q1     NaN     1.0  NaN
2017Q2     1.0     NaN  2.0
```

Comment: I was missing the group by so it convert it to numeric values, R does not required any such group by so I did not expect it here too, thanks for your reply

Comment: @Vineet You're welcome. I thought you'd appreciate the `ggplot` style plotting too, coming from R.

Answer (score 11):

## Another Alternative

`data_frame.attribute_name.value_counts().plot.bar()`

## Example

`iris_data.sample(3)`

[image: Iris dataset sample]

`iris_data.Species.value_counts().plot.bar()`

[image: Iris dataset class bar plot]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html).

Last plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df = dummyData.groupby(['quarter','brand']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
#alternative solution
#df = pd.crosstab(dummyData['quarter'], dummyData['brand'])
print (df)
brand    Apple  Google  MS
quarter                   
2015Q1       1       0   0
2016Q1       0       1   0
2017Q2       1       0   2

df.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]